# Объясните как работает код сортировки

Tags: javascript

```js
let users = [
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" }
];

function byField(field) {
  return (a, b) => a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
}
users.sort(byField('name'));


users.forEach(user => console.log(user.name));
```

1. field передается 'name' и находится в users;
2. Но как происходит сортировка в стрелочной функции если в параметры а,b  ничего не передавали ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Помимо всего прочего в [функциональном программировании](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) есть такое понятие **функция высшего порядка** (high order function).

Функция высшего порядка - это функция принимающая в качестве аргументов другие функции или возвращающая другую функцию в качестве результата.

Основная идея состоит в том, что функции имеют тот же статус, что и другие объекты.

—-

Теперь о Вашем коде, функция `byField` -функция высшего порядка, которая возвращает стрелочную функцию с двумя входными аргументами a и b.

В свою очередь функция массива `sort` тоже функция высшего порядка которая принимает в качестве аргумента функцию.

Алгоритм сортировки,реализованный в методе `sort`, грубо говоря, перебирает пары значений и делает перестановки.

Функция, которую Вы передаете будет применяться к парам значений в процессе сортировки, для выяснения факта, какое значение в исследуемой паре больше.

—-

PS: Если Вы добавите логгирование в стрелочную функцию, которую Вы передаете в метод сортировки, Вы увидите сколько раз и с какими аргументами она вызвалась во время этой сортировки.

Comment: кажется я понял в sort передается способ сравнения как здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#preobrazovanie-massiva разница в том что  в ссылке sort работает с числами, а тут с объектами верно ?

Comment: @user349791 именно так

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а что вы имеете в виду когда говорите логгирование это если написать `debuger`?

Comment: @Demon__ANT вообще я думал про console.log, но и debugger сойдет